# import sklearn in python

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn

I installed miniconda for Windows10 successfully and then I could install numpy, scipy, sklearn successfully, but when I run `import sklearn` in python IDLE I receive `No module named 'sklearn'` in anaconda prompt. It recognized my python version, which was 3.6.5, correctly. I don't know what's wrong, can anyone tell me how do I import modules in IDLE ?

Comment: Did you create a new conda environment for the installed packages?  If so, you need to use `activate <environmentName>` before running Python

Comment: Hi James, thanks for comment, yeah I created a new conda (I created  in anaconda prompt, is it correct?) and I activated the environment( in anaconda prompt and cmd). I just tried to install sklearn , numpy and scipy in cmd and they were succesfully installed in my environment , but now when I "import sklearn" in IDLE, I receive :ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why bot Download the full anaconda and this will install everything you need to start which includes Spider IDE, Rstudio, Jupyter and all the needed modules..

I have been using anaconda without any error and i will recommend you try it out.

Comment: sorry as I'm beginner in python and machine learning , i'm not sure if I can apply machine learning algorithms in Spider IDE. can you give me some information about it?

Comment: Spyder is just and IDE.. Dont worry, I will run you through..

Firstly go to https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows and download anaconda version of you windows operating system..

The rest are not easy..

Dont forget to mark my answer as the right answer.

Comment: Why did you downvote my answer instead of upvoting it .. I dont understand

Comment: Hi Michael, I downloaded and it's installing, thanks for helping me . I'm sorry for devoting , I just understand it right now and I tried to upvote it but I couldn't. So sorry for this , it's first time I'm here and I didn't know what I'm doing!!